# Power dissipation in a circuit

Tags: power, resistors, power-dissipation

What would be the power across 5ohms resistor and 3 to 7ohms (variable) resistor?Is the power same or different?why?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The power is different, because power is defined by voltage and current.

P = U * I 
U = I * R 
P = U*U/R

Case 1: R1=5, R2=3, R12= 8, P= 25/8 ~3W
Case 2: R1=5, R2=5, R12= 10, P= 25/10 ~2.5W
Case 3: R1=5, R2=7, R12= 12, P= 25/12 ~2W

Answer (score 0):

The power dissipated by each resistor will depend on the total resistance in the circuit.

To find the power dissipated in each resistor, you first find the current using Ohm's Law: I = V/R, where R is the total resistance in the circuit.

You can then find the power in each resistor using P = I^2 R, where R is the value of the resistor of interest.